# Conditional regex in python

Tags: python, regex, conditional-statements

I want to match a string if the firstline of the string contains the given "sub" string. Is this possible in python using a oneliner regex ?

```
string="abcd - testing xxx
foo bar
end"
```

if firstline of string contains:

```
"abcd - testing"
```

Match the whole string:

```
"abcd - testing xxx
foo bar
end"
```

The problem is the output is read by another python program, which is outside of my control.

I can only supply the program with a oneline regex...

Thank you.

Comment: You may not need a regex: `my_string.startswith("abcd - testing")`

Comment: What did you try and what issue you had with the pattern you tried?

Comment: Do you mean the "regex" is read by another program... not the "output". "Output" implies that you are referring to the matched string.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
string = """abcd - testing xxx
foo bar
end"""

sub = "abcd - testing"

def match(string, sub):
    return string if sub in string.splitlines()[0] else ''

print match(string, sub)
```

- `splitlines()` will split your main string into lines
- `[0]` will choose the first line
- `in` will return true if your sub string is contained in the first line

Comment: Is it possible to split string within an oneline regular expression ?

Comment: Why do you must use a regex?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This will work.

```
^.*abcd - testing.*\n(?:.*\n?)+$
```